# Matlab Data Import from a text file

Tags: matlab, import

How do i import data of the following format.

```
1.0,X
.,-1.0
```

The size of the table may differ. As in the next file can also be a valid input file

```
.,.,.,1.0
.,X,.,-1.0
.,.,.,.
```

I have tried doing this using readtable to read the data and then use strcmp to assign the values to a different matrix but it doesnt work. What am i doing wrong.

Code:

```
foo = readtable(environment_file)
bar = zeros(size(foo,1),size(foo,2));

for i = 1:size(foo,1)
   for j = 1:size(foo,2)
        if strcmp(foo(i,j),'.')
            bar(i,j) = 3;
        elseif strcmp(foo(i,j),'X')
            bar(i,j) = -10;
        elseif strcmp(foo(i,j),'1.0')
            bar(i,j) = 1;
        elseif strcmp(foo(i,j),'-1.0')
            bar(i,j) = -1;
        end
   end
end
bar
```

Comment: The format of your data file is not immediately clear. What does the X stand for? Is it a character or a number variable? Please give a complete description/example of the data file.

Comment: yes it is a character

Comment: i can ignore the ',' but want to store rest of the values in a matrix

Comment: are the dots also a character?

Comment: yes. I am replacing their values with an integer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. One is that `readtable` reads the file as a table and takes the first row in the file as the names of the columns. So therefore, you should have the names at the top of the file.

Secondly, to access the contents of the table you need to use {} and not (). Also, there is no need to use for loops as you can use logical indexing to assign values to your matrix bar_b. Therefore, the changed code is as follows:

```
dataArray = readtable('environment_file.txt');
[n, m] = size(dataArray);
bar_b = zeros(n, m);
bar_b(strcmp(dataArray{:, :}, '.')) = 3;
bar_b(strcmp(dataArray{:, :}, 'X')) = -10;
bar_b(strcmp(dataArray{:, :}, '1.0')) = 1;
bar_b(strcmp(dataArray{:, :}, '-1.0')) = -1;
```